# querySelectorAll in a x-for loop

Tags: selectors-api, alpine.js

I'm trying to get all the `data-xxx` in a `x-for` loop but the `nodeList` is always empty.

```html
<section id="content" x-data="animate()" x-init="init()">
   <h1>Title here</h1>

   <template x-for="i in items">
      <div class="box" data-class-in="fadeIn" data-class-out="fadeOut">
          <h2>Content Here</h2>
      </div>
   </template>
</section>
```

and this is my js code

```js
function animate() {
   return {
      items: 12,
      target = null,
      init: function () {
         this.target = document.querySelectorAll("[data-class-in], [data-class-out]");
         console.log(this.target);
      },
   }
}
```

Tried also with `this.$el.querySelectorAll("[data-class-in], [data-class-out]")`. nothing happen

Any help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the initial `x-for` rendering to happen, in Alpine that's done with `$nextTick()` (see the docs https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/#nexttick)

```html
function animate() {
   return {
      items: 12,
      target = null,
      init: function () {
         // setTimeout(() => {}, 0) should also work
         this.$nextTick(() => {
           this.target = document.querySelectorAll("[data-class-in], [data-class-out]");
           console.log(this.target);
         });
      },
   }
}
```